# what does this command do: sed -i "s/bind .*/bind 127.0.0.1/g" /etc/redis/redis.conf

Tags: 22.04, redis

I'm new to redis database and I want to know in the process of redis configuration what this command do:

```
sed -i "s/bind .*/bind 127.0.0.1/g" /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Comment: To the downvoter if he/she reads is: I myself do not mind these kind of q's even when it is  rather basic. Better to ask then end up messing something up.

Comment: And this is why these platforms exist, in my opinion, thank you again dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It alters `/etc/redis/redis.conf` by searching (`/s` for search) lines starting with "bind" and replace all (`/g` for global) the whole line by `bind 127.0.0.1`

Example:

```
~/tmp$ more test
bind 11111 11111
brrrrrrnd bind
bind 2222222
~/tmp$ sed -i "s/bind .*/bind 127.0.0.1/g" test
~/tmp$ more test
bind 127.0.0.1
brrrrrrnd bind
bind 127.0.0.1
```

It means Redis will only receive local (so no external) connections on that socket.

Comment: thank you for this explication